# Как реализовать синглтоны как в спринге, репозитории или дао

Tags: java, apache, spring, apache-modules

Работаю со стеком технологий  OSGi- Apache karaf + Apache Felix. Проект состоит из спагети кода. Пытаюсь отрефакторить, поправить, улучшить. Но с  OSGi столкнулся впервые.

Что хочу сделать:

1. Использовать синглтоны, как в спринге @Autowired. Есть ли что-то подобное в OSGi?
2. использовать Repository  или  DAO паттерн, как в спринге. Есть ли такое в OSGi?

Сразу скажу, что я пытался связать с спрингом но ничего не вышло. пробовал по примеру [с хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/128653/) но пример запустил а вот в рабочий проект встроить не смог

Если нет реализации синглтонов, может быть, просто использовать обычный паттерн и написать свои?

У меня нативный  sql, голые запросы, и нет ORMок.

Comment: здесь принята практика: один *конкретный* вопрос — один (и более) ответ. задайте, пожалуйста, второй из вопросов, воспользовавшись кнопкой «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы, а из этого вопроса его лучше убрать. так же, как и излишнюю для понимания вопроса информацию.

Comment: Если Java8, то Вместо \@Autowired используем теперь уже стандартный \@Inject.